# Returning a string from a method defined in another class returns nothing

Tags: java, string, class, methods, return

I've read around and tried to find a answer but have been unable to. I've created a method which works in its own class, to have two string parameters and then use these to return a string value. I then have tried to call this method defined in one class in another class but i get a null pointer exception. I've tried several things , tested different ways to do it but have been unable to get it to work. Please excuse my poor programming convention, i'm just starting out. This is the method which is meant to return the String:

```
public class Cipher {   

public  static String encrypt(String Tobeencrypted , String key) 
{                   
   row row[] = new row[26];


   for (int counter = 0; counter < 26 ; counter++ )
   {
      row[counter] = new row();

      for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 26 ; counter2++){
          int charnumber = counter + 97 + counter2;
              if (charnumber > 122){
                  charnumber = charnumber - 26;
              }
          row[counter].alpha[counter2] = (char)(charnumber);
      }
   }

   int numberofcharacters = Tobeencrypted.length();
   int keylength = key.length();
   char keychar[] = new char[numberofcharacters];

   int keyindexvalue = 0;
   for (int counter = 0 ; counter < numberofcharacters ; counter++){
   if (keyindexvalue == keylength) 
           keyindexvalue = keyindexvalue - keylength;
       keychar[counter] = key.charAt(keyindexvalue++); 
   }

   char textchars[] = new char[numberofcharacters];
     for (int counter = 0 ; counter < numberofcharacters ; counter++){
     textchars[counter] = Tobeencrypted.charAt(counter);
   }
   String encryptedstring = "";
     for (int counter = 0 ; counter < numberofcharacters ; counter++){
     textchars[counter] = row[(int(keychar[counter])-97].alpha[(int)                       
         (textchars[counter])-97];
     encryptedstring = encryptedstring + textchars[counter];    
     }
     return encryptedstring;
 }
```

This method works perfectly when i have a main method in the Cipher class using it. But the method returns nothing when used in the following code. The files are all in the same source folder:

```
 public class testingmethod {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new         File("C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/test.txt"));

    int counter = 0;
    String random ="";
    while ( diskScanner.hasNext()){

        random = diskScanner.next();
        counter++;      
    }
    //counter tells you the exact amount of strings there are if there are 10   strings counter = 10
    String strings[] = new String[counter];
    int counter2 = 5;
    while ( diskScanner.hasNext()){
        strings[counter2] = diskScanner.next();
        counter2++;     
    }
    String encrypted[] = new String[counter];
    Cipher cipher = new Cipher();
    PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/test.txt"));
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What password would you like to use? (please make this one word)");
    for ( int counter3 = 0 ; counter3 < counter ; counter3++){
        encrypted[counter3] = cipher.encrypt(strings[counter3], password);
        diskWriter.print(encrypted[counter3] + "    ");
        if(counter3 % 11 == 0) diskWriter.println("");
    }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();}

}
```

}

Ive made changes according to all your lovely help and the print statement worked but now i have a null pointer exception which was the problem i used the tobeencrypted = String() to solve.

The error is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at introtojava.Cipher.encrypt(Cipher.java:43)
at introtojava.testingmethod.main(testingmethod.java:34)
```

Many thanks,

Isaac

Comment: Try `println` instead of `print`? Maybe stdout is not being flushed.

Comment: Just tried that after your sugguestion but still doesnt return anything

Comment: The answer they gave you are correct. I'd suggest to start writing code using the Java code conventions as it'll be easier for everyone (the future yourself included) to understand your code :)

Comment: The problem with that is i forget them i do try but get engrossed it trying to get it to work that i forget

Comment: And what is line 43???

Comment: int numberofcharacters = Tobeencrypted.length(); is line 43 in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You intentionally lose your parameter's reference to the string to encrypt with this line:

```
Tobeencrypted = new String();
```

Then you get the length of that string, which is now 0:

```
int numberofcharacters = Tobeencrypted.length();
```

So, there are no iterations in this `for` loop:

```
for (int counter = 0 ; counter < numberofcharacters ; counter++){
```

which is where you are building the return string, `encryptedstring`.

It looks like you can just remove this line:

```
Tobeencrypted = new String();
```

Comment: Your a star mate that worked wonders, there was a reason for me doing that to resolve another problem yet its not reoccuring that problem when i remove it so all is well thanks !!!

Comment: Now ive removed that comment and am using the full method now i get a null pointer exceptioin from somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the line

```
Tobeencrypted = new String();
```